# Cast a list into a list of objects in dart

Tags: json, rest, flutter, dart

the code below makes a rest call to a node.js server, which returns a json containing a series of values ​​these values ​​must be inserted in a list by casting the values ​​in a **Cantiere** type object. How can I go about doing this? 
What I want to do is convert every single json into a construction-type object and then insert them in a list.

**JSON Call Flutter:**

```
      static Future<List> Ricerca(Utente u, int IdCantiere, String NomeCantiere,
          String RagioneSociale, bool isUtente) async {
        var ret;
        Map map = {
          'IdUtente': u.GetIdUtente(),
          'IdCantiere': IdCantiere,
          'NomeCantiere': "a",
          'RagioneSociale': RagioneSociale,
          'CheckBoxCantieriCreatiDaUtenteLoggato': isUtente
        };
        String value = await apiRequest("/cantieri/ricerca", map);

//The ret variable holds the json, what I want to do is create a list of Cantiere type objects.
        ret = json.decode(value); 
        return (ret as Iterable<dynamic> ?? const <dynamic>[])
    .map((dynamic jsonObject) => Cantiere(
          new Cliente(
              jsonObject["IdCliente"] as int,
              jsonObject["RagioneSociale"] as String,
              jsonObject["Filiale"] as String,),
          jsonObject["IdCantiere"] as int,
          jsonObject["NomeCantiere"] as String,
          jsonObject["DescrizioneEstesa"] as String,
          jsonObject["Tipologia"] as String,
          jsonObject["Stato"] as String,
          jsonObject["StatoFatturazione"] as String,
          jsonObject["DataCreazione"] as String,
        ))
    .toList();
      }
```

**Cantiere.dart and Cliente.dart**

```
    class Cliente {
          int _IdCliente;
          String _RagioneSociale;
          String _Filiale;
          Cliente(this._IdCliente, this._RagioneSociale, this._Filiale);


          String GetRagioneSociale() {
            return this._RagioneSociale;
          }
        }
            //Classe che rappresenta il cantiere
class Cantiere {

  String _NomeCantiere,
      _Tipologia,
      _Stato,
      _StatoFatturazione,
      _DescrizioneEstesa,
      _DataCreazione;
  int _IdCantiere;
  Cliente _c;

  Cantiere(
      this._c,
      this._IdCantiere,
      this._NomeCantiere,
      this._DescrizioneEstesa,
      this._Tipologia,
      this._Stato,
      this._StatoFatturazione,
      this._DataCreazione);

            }
```

**JSON Example:**

```
[
    {
        "IdCantiere": 4,
        "IdCliente": 40,
        "Filiale": "SEDE",
        "RagioneSociale": "Ca asas",
        "NomeCantiere": "sala dd",
        "DataCreazioneCantiere": "2017-08-04T18:20:31.333Z",
        "Tipologia": "Consuntivo",
        "StatoCantiere": "Chiuso",
        "StatoFatturazione": 1,
        "DescrizioneEstesa": "asasas"
    },

        "IdCantiere": 5,
        "IdCliente": 40,
        "Filiale": "SEDE",
        "RagioneSociale": "Ca asas",
        "NomeCantiere": "sala dd",
        "DataCreazioneCantiere": "2017-08-04T18:20:31.333Z",
        "Tipologia": "Consuntivo",
        "StatoCantiere": "Chiuso",
        "StatoFatturazione": 1,
        "DescrizioneEstesa": "asasas"
    }

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `jsonDecode` does is actually converting a JSON string into a sequence of `List`s and `Map`s with included primitive types, depending on the fact if it is a JSON array or JSON object or a JSON primitive.

So, the type of the output (based on the JSON snippet provided) is `List` which contains a number of `Map`s (but it is not to say that the type really is `List<Map>`).

What is necessary to get the wanted result is to map every JSON object from the decoded JSON to the needed object type:

```
return (ret as Iterable<dynamic> ?? const <dynamic>[])
  .map((dynamic jsonObject) => 
    Cliente(
      jsonObject["IdCliente"] as int, 
      jsonObject["RagioneSociale"] as String, 
      jsonObject["Filiale"] as String,
    )
  )
  .toList();
```

Comment: But my Cantiere object is also composed of the Cliente object. How do I apply your reasoning to my code? Then the decode should be removed?

Comment: extend the parsing logic to support the model of choice then.

the sample of how to parse the `jsonDecode` result is provided in the answer.

construct `Cantiere` object rather than `Cliente` with ad-hoc fields retrieval from the `jsonObject`, that should do the trick.

Comment: I added your reasoning in the code above but when I run it I have the following error: Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: that's probably because in `Cantiere` class variable `_StatoFatturazione` has a type of `String`, and in JSON field named `StatoFatturazione` is a JSON primitive of integer type. you can resolve it like this: `(jsonObject["StatoFatturazione"] as int).toString()` or by changing the type of `_StatoFatturazione` variable to `int` rather than leave it to be `String`. The error message itself clearly states that casting of a variable of `int` type to a `String` type is impossible